# How to push modified code file to bitbucket through git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need one help. I have an existing repository in bit bucket and I need to commit some/all modified file again into that repository through git command. Here I need those git command to upload all modified files.

Comment: Git is a _project_ based version control system, and when you `git push` you always conceptually push _every_ file in your project.  You might want to review a basic Git tutorial if you are getting stuck at this point.

Comment: Have you tried using the `git push` command? What difficulties are you having?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [Bitbucket help page on `git push`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing#git-push)?

Answer (score 3):

1. To chck status of current git folder

> git status

1. to push one single file

> `git add filename.<extension>`

to push every changes in you git folder

> `git add .   or`git add --all

2. commit changes with messages

> ```
> `git commit -m "<ur msg here>"`
> ```

3. Dont forget to add the git repo in  remote address if not.

> git remote add origin

4. Push the changes

> git push -u origin master

Answer (score 0):

Add your files:

```
    git add --all
```

Stage/Commit:

```
    git commit -am 'description of your changes'
```

Push to BitBucket:

```
    git push origin [branchname]
```

Comment: How to know which repository to push.

Answer (score 0):

Use this following command to push modified code file to bitbucket - repository

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Your message"
git push origin [branch name]
```

Comment: Can I push only a single modified file to a particular folder of that repository ?

Comment: Yes you can push a single file by using this command -- 
**git add filename.<extension>**

Comment: But i have many repository how it will push the required directory.

Comment: ok here is the working process if you have a bitbucket repo -- 
1) clone the git repo (you want to modify) in your machine 
    `git clone (your git repo URL) https://xyz@bitbucket.org/yourRepo.git`
2) Modify the code/file you want

And then follow this command step by step by using your terminal/command prompt, git shell etc.. 

**`git status` (check your modified file)
`git add -A`  (add your file to git repo)
`git commit -m` "Your message" (add your commit description)
and finally, `git push origin [branch name]` (Push local files to bitbucket repo)**

Comment: **But i have many repository** ??? 
I am confused, I think you are talking about the branch
To check your current branch  use this command 
`git branch`  
To checkout another branch use
`git checkout  [branch name]`
modify your code, and follow the before comment working process.

Comment: I just wanted to say i have many projects in bit-bucket. and i need to upload the files to particular folder. At my first commit i was using `git remote add origin https://subhrajyoti@bitbucket.org/subhrajyoti/project1.git`. so that it was pointing to one single repo.